# How to remove electrical harness from 2005 Dodge ram 1500 valve cover?

Tags: dodge, ram, wiring-harness

My ram 1500 is leaking oil from the valve cover gasket. It has 160,000 miles on it. I want to replace the valve cover gasket and to do so I must remove the ~10 bolts holding on the valve cover. Three of these bolts have a electrical wiring harness pressed down onto them with some bolt clips.

[image: electrical wiring harness]

[image: Bolt clip]

I have tried to get the bolt clips off by squeezing the clips and hoping they would release, but haven't had any luck.Hard to access too.

[image: Two of the bolt clips on the harness from underneath the truck]

Does anyone know of a tool or a method to get these off without breaking them?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pry it off. Get a screwdriver under it and wiggle it. The harness is plastic which have what I'd call "inverted christmas trees" in them. They are designed to hold onto the end of the stud (or whatever is sticking up there). Just put a screwdriver at the base and carefully twist it. The plastic part will pull right up.

Comment: Thanks - that makes a lot of sense. I was starting to think that way so this confirms it.